# Charge distribution in a sphere in uniform field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, classical-electrodynamics

So my teacher was telling about how if we place an uncharged conducting sphere inside a uniform electric field , the charges so distribute that the E field inside them becomes zero. He told us that this will come out to be a complex distribution.

Is there any way we can calculate this distribution ???
Please give the proof /derivation ??
How many such distribution are possible ??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, although you require some advanced math (Legendre polynomials, basic Fourier series). An excellent introduction to this is Chapter 3 of Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics

(In fact, the entire book is excellent. If you ever want to study undergrad-level Electrodynamics, this is *the* book to study from)

Comment: Can you please give the proof / derivation too ?? Basically your regular JEE aspirant who has only read it till chapter 2